# JWPlayer - JWConfig error

Tags: ios, objective-c, jwplayer

We are developing video playing process using JWPlayer's trial version, but it's crashing at the line of `JWPlayerController` initialising with JWConfig:

```
JWPlayer=[[JWPlayerController alloc]initWithConfig:config1];
```

Please suggest me to get out of this issue.

Comment: Not nearly enough information for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Are you using the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 2):

here is how you create a player instance in your view controller:

```
JWConfig *conf = [JWConfig configWithContentURL:@"your file here"];
self.player = [[JWPlayerController alloc] initWithConfig:conf];
self.player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 150);
[self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
```

Comment: @Vetri - Can you approve this answer?